# How to handle the content between unmanaged dll and C#

Tags: c#, c, dll, pinvoke

Hi i got problems to handle information between an unmanaged dll and my C# code.

The function in my C dll is:

```
int import_large_string(struct sha_struct *sha_s,
                   const char *large_string);
```

That import the large_string and transform into sha_s, the struct sha_struct is the following:

```
struct sha_struct 
{
    struct information  *info;
    struct info_cfg cfg;
};
```

And the information struct is something like

```
struct information 
{
int             version;
char            serial_number[16];
uint16_t        exp_date;
};
```

In C# i imported the function import_large_string like this:

```
[DllImport("functionalDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "import_large_string", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static int import_large_string(ref sha_struct sha_s, string large_string);
```

When i called the function, it suppose to store information in `sha_struct sha_s`, but i only have a random 8 digit number in `sha_s.information.version` not in the whole struct, what am I doing wrong?

> **Edited**
>
> My structs in C# are:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct sha_struct
    {
        public information t;
        public info_cfg cfg;
    };

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct information
    {
        public int version;
        public string serial_number;
        public ushort exp_date;
    };

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct info_cfg
    {
        public string release_version;
        public string release_string;
        public string release_password;
    };
```

Comment: Please add your C# versions of your structs. They likely aren't being marshaled correctly.

Comment: @vcsjones i updated the versions

Comment: You need to use ByValTStr on the inline string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @DavidHeffernan, you want to use the MarshalAs attribute on your string field:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct information
    {
        public int version;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=16)]
        public string serial_number;
        public ushort exp_date;
    };
```

As illustrated on [this documentation link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h(v=vs.110).aspx#cpcondefaultmarshalingforstringsanchor2).

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem and others questions about Marshaling